# AngularJS conditional formatting

Tags: angularjs

I just started with AngularJS and want to show some properties in brackets. The data obviously do not contain brackets.

something like this:

`({{property}})`

But how to detect if the property is undefined to not show the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several simple ways are `ng-show`, `ng-class` or `ng-if`

```
<span ng-if="property">({{property}})</span>
<span ng-show="property">({{property}})</span>
<span ng-class="{'hideMeClass" : !property}">({{property}})</span>
```